# Convert Android image into a file that MATLAB can read

Tags: android, image, matlab, image-processing, bitmap

I´m working on a project related with image recognition using MATLAB and I'm currently using an Android app to help with some pre-processing steps. I thought it was going to be easy to work with matrices instead of bitmaps. I finally managed to finish my algorithm and to import it to Eclipse. The problem is that I realize that I don't know how to convert a `Bitmap` image into something that MATLAB can read in for the purposes of my algorithm.

Do you have any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you have an image stored in the `Bitmap` class and you want to save this to file locally on your Android device.  You then want to load this image into MATLAB for your image recognition algorithm.

Given the fact that your image is in memory via Android, you can use the method `compress`: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))

You'd then use this and save the image to file, and then you can load it into MATLAB, using [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) for example.

Here's some sample code you could write for your Android app.  Assuming your Bitmap instance is stored in a variable called `bmp`, do:

```
FileOutputStream out = null; // For writing to the device
String filename = "out.png"; // Output file name

// Full path to save
// This accesses the pictures directory of your device and saves the file there
String output = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), filename);

try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(filename); // Open up a new file stream
    // Save the Bitmap instance to file
    // First param - type of image
    // Second param - Compression factor
    // Third param - The full path to the file
    // Note: PNG is lossless, so the compression factor (100) is ignored
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 
}
// Catch any exceptions that happen 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
// Execute this code even if exception happens
finally {
    try {
        // Close the file if it was open to write
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    } 
    // Catch any exceptions with the closing here
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code will save the image to your default Pictures directory on your device.  Once you pull out that image, you can read the image into MATLAB by using `imread`:

```
im = imread('out.png');
```

`im` would thus be the raw RGB pixels of the image that you can now use for your image recognition algorithm.

Comment: Sorry if I didnt explain myself correctly, by a Matlab image I meant that precisely. Thank you for your answer, it was truly useful

Comment: @AlvaroNav - No problem at all.  Glad I could help!